# Непонятные каракули в txt

Tags: c++

```
cout <<endl<< "Что вводить?: ";
string write1;
cin.get();
getline(cin, write1);

ofstream Lol;
Lol.open("Data\\Seriali.txt", ios::app);
Lol << endl << write1;
Lol.close();

cout << "\n1. Вернуться обратно\n2. Завершить программу\nВыберите пункт: ";
short viborr1;
cin >> viborr1;

if (viborr1 == 1) {
    goto spawn;
} else {
    cout << sps;
    return 0;
}
```

После ввода данных в поле, вместо того чтобы в txt файле показывался нужный текст, показывает просто какую то дичь.. Что делать? Язык ввода русский. Могу предоставить полный код программы

**Использую VSCode, код запускается во встроенном терминале а не в обычном от виндовс, но как я думаю это сути не меняет**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это означает, что символы не опознаны. Поищите в Интернете, как настроить кодировку на UTF-8 в C++

Comment: Вставил строку ```setlocale(LC_ALL, "utf-8");``` и не помогло.. txt файл тоже в utf8